# How to connect to a UDP video broadcast with GStreamer in C

Tags: c, gtk, media-player, gstreamer

I have a small program that uses the `GStreamer` library to play videos from local files and videos on webservers using HTTP. How does one go about connecting to a UDP video broadcast in C using `GStreamer`?

For example, what is required to play the streaming video at this hypothetical URI?
10.0.11.255:9001

I tried:

```
// using playbin2 connect to UDP broadcast
g_object_set (data.playbin2, "uri", "udp://10.0.11.255:9001", NULL);
```

Then I try to start the stream with the following:

```
/* Start playing */
    if( gst_element_set_state (data.playbin2, GST_STATE_PLAYING) == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE )
    {
        g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref (data.playbin2);
        return( -1 );
    }
```

and I get the failure to change state message.

I've done searches on google and have not found anything useful.

EDIT: After some more googling, I found out about [udpsrc](https://developer.gnome.org/gst-plugins-libs/0.10/gst-plugins-good-plugins-udpsrc.html). However, I can't figure out how to use it in C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the UDP broadcast stream isn't getting forwarded to the virtual machine I'm doing my development on.

Using `playbin2` and setting it's `uri property` to `udp://0.0.0.0:9001` is all that is required to cause `playbin2` to properly create the needed source element.

Answer (score 0):

**udpsrc** is a network source that reads UDP packets from the network. You cannot use it to connect to a remote host, you can only read data from a port.

However, if you have a multicast-group set up, then can read from multicast groups by setting the "multicast-group" property to the IP address of the multicast group.

If you use:

```
g_object_set (data.udpsrc, "uri", "udp://10.0.11.255:9001", NULL);
```

Then that means you're reading data from a mulitcast group whose ip address is 10.0.11.255, not connecting to the host.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using a playbin2 bin element that doesn't contain a udpsrc element. I would have thought that specifying playbin2 uri=udp://0.0.0.0:9001/ that the playbin2 bin would have automatically created the needed src element.